# Unable to run the failed test cases using IRetryAnalyzer

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am having a test case that is purely data-driven. My objective is to rerun the tests which failed at least one more time again. The issue I am facing here is saying if the retry count is set to 3 and I have a data-driven test in the below fashion,

```
    @Test(dataProvider="PositiveScenarios",groups= "smoke",retryAnalyzer = utils.Retry.class)
    public void positiveScenariosTest(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) throws InterruptedException {
    }

And the Retry class is like below

    package utils;

    import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;

    public class Retry  implements IRetryAnalyzer{

    int counter = 1;
    int retryMaxLimit = 3;

     public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (counter < retryMaxLimit) {
            System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (retryMaxLimit - counter + 1) + " out of " + retryMaxLimit);
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Let's say I have 10 tests. If the 4th test fails, the 4th test retries 3 times ( which is good ). 
After this, say, if the 6th test fails, the 6th test runs only once and not 3 times.
I was expecting the 6th tests to run 3 times before failing.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I do not have any specific TestNG listeners here ( like on test failure )
Do I need to have one? If that's the case, how the first test failure ran 3 times? Is there an initializer I am missing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using the latest version of TestNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out at last. Not sure whethere this is a TestNG issue. 
What I did was reset the counter each time when the test passes (even after 2nd round  or 3 round ) like below

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void AfterTest(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {         

    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {

        Retry retry = new Retry();
        retry.resetCounter();
    }       
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {         
    }

    }
```

Hope this will be useful for some one. Thanks again. It seems like a hack but working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `@Override` annotation is missing above the `retry(ITestResult result)` method in your `Retry` class.
It should be like:

```
package utils;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class Retry  implements IRetryAnalyzer{

int counter = 1;
int retryMaxLimit = 3;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
if (counter < retryMaxLimit) {
       System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (retryMaxLimit - counter + 1) + " out of " + retryMaxLimit);
       counter++;
       return true;
       }
   return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I tried that. It did not help